# Momentarily Disable Swiping on a PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have a pageViewController holding several scrollViews, each holding their own image. The issue is that when someone tries to pan an image, the pageViewController recognizes that as a swipe and attempts to move to the next image. Is there any way to disable this?

Conceptually I believe this is what I should do-

```
if(scrollView.scrollScale > 1){
  pageViewController.scrollingEnabled = false
} else{
  pageViewController.scrollingEnabled = true
}
```

This way while the user is zoomed in past a 1:1 scale they cannot swipe between pictures.

I attempted this within the viewDidLayoutSubviews method of my pageViewController.

```
for(var index: Int = 0; index < self.gestureRecognizers.count; index++){

  self.gestureRecognizers[index].requireGestureRecognizerToFail(scrollView!.panGestureRecognizer)

}
```

This did not affect the issue of swiping between pictures instead of panning within a zoomed picture.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'requireGestureRecognizerToFail:' method of 'UIGestureRecognizer'.

'UIPageViewController' has a 'gestureRecognizers' property. 'UIScrollView' has a 'panGestureRecognizer' and a 'pinchGestureRecognizer'. So something like

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
 [recognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:scrollview.pinchGestureRecognizer]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain conceptually how this would work? In your example, the pageViewController would only act on gestures if the scrollView's pinch gesture was unable to execute?

Comment: if you have scroll as transitionStyle, pageViewController doesn't have gestures